# using airflow plugin to import external python function

Tags: python, airflow

On `on_failure_callback` I am calling `sns` method to send notification which is working fine.
I want to declare `sns` function as a separate function using airflow plugins.

```
import boto3
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# t1, t2, t3 and t4 are examples of tasks created using operators

def sns(state):
  client = boto3.client('sns',aws_access_key_id='abcd',aws_secret_access_key='abcd',region_name='us-east-1')
  response = client.publish(
    TargetArn='Topicarn',
    Message='Test')

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_3',
    bash_command='fail',
    on_failure_callback=sns,
    dag=dag)
```

Thanks,
Rajeev

Comment: Have you read the official documentation on Plugins? https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html - there is a very nice example there which you can try for yourself. If you have a specific problem while doing that, then you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have read the official documentation.Looking answer for below questions:

Comment: 1.Which base class I should use?

Comment: 2.How I should configure plugin folder ?

Comment: 3.How to call particular method from python code which is there in plugin folder to DAG ?

Comment: You should update your original question with those points. It will get answered then. The way it is now is too broad

Comment: The idea of using `Operator` as a `callable` seems *counter-intuitive*. Any particular reason you want to do that? I can think of 2 *better* alternatives **[1]** Put actual functionality in a `@staticmethod` function within the `snsoperator` class and then invoke it within `execute()` method as well use it as `callable` wherever needed. **[2]** Do the same thing except keeping function in a separate `python` *utility* `module` rather than inside the `operator` class

Comment: In Airflow we have plugin concept to integrate external features to its core.So thought of going with the idea of using sending AWS sns notification using plugin

Answer (score 1):

(replying to actual questions posted to comments, please move those to the original question)

1. Since this will be a basically a notification operator, you should inherit from `BaseOperator`.
2. Plugin folder is usually located in the project's root, next to the `dag` folder.
3. As for the plugin itself, once you inherit from `AirflowPlugin`, it will be accessible for import as `airflow.operators.my_operator`. You can use it as any other operator.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me :

plugin code :

```
import boto3
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults

class snsoperator(BaseOperator):
  @apply_defaults
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

   super(snsoperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("calling execute")
    client = boto3.client('sns', aws_access_key_id='abc',
                              aws_secret_access_key='abc', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = client.publish(
            TargetArn='abc',
            Message='Test')

class snsplugin(AirflowPlugin):
  name = "snsplugin"
  operators = [snsoperator]
```

DAG code :

```
import boto3
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.snsplugin import snsoperator

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_3',
    bash_command='fail',
    on_failure_callback=snsoperator(task_id='sns'),
    dag=dag)
```